# How to Extract Database Connection Information from JInitiator 1.1.8.16 Files?

Tags: oracle11g, jinitiator

I'm currently tasked with extracting database connection information from legacy files associated with JInitiator 1.1.8.16. Our organization relies on these files for database access, and I need to migrate this functionality to a more modern setup.

Within the JInitiator 1.1.8.16 files, particularly in the lib/security directory, I've found several .x509 files and other security-related assets. However, I'm struggling to locate the specific database connection details such as IP address, port, and other configuration parameters needed for database connectivity.

I've attempted to use OpenSSL to analyze the .x509 files and other tools for text extraction, but without much success. Is there a recommended approach or tool for extracting database connection information from JInitiator files?

Any insights, guidance, or tools that could help me extract the necessary database connection details from these files would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

I attempted to use the OpenSSL command line tool to read the contents of a .x509 file located at C:\Oracle\JInitiator 1.1.8.16\lib\security\cwm.x509.

Comment: Those kind of connection details will not be in x509 certs. They would be in some other application configuration file.